# HAVING row exist

Tags: mysql

Following database sample

```
   id   |   date   |  customer |  ...
-----------------------------------------
1        2016-07-05      1
2        2016-07-05      2
3        2016-07-06      1
4        2016-07-07      1
5        2016-07-07      2
```

I want to select all customers which have an entry at `2016-07-07`, but *not* at `2016-07-06`.

At first, I thought I'd do this using `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '2016-07-07' )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '2016-07-06' )
  GROUP BY customer
```

but since `WHERE` is executed **before** `GROUP BY`, the result can only by empty - there IS a record in `table` at `2016-07-06`.

So, using `HAVING`, how would I do this? I am having difficulties checking for row existance in a `HAVING` clause. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
  GROUP BY customer
    HAVING exists date '2016-07-07'
    AND not exists date '2016-07-06'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `customer` and take only those groups having at least one `date` entry for `2016-07-07` and none for `2016-07-06`

```
SELECT customer 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY customer
HAVING sum(date = '2016-07-07') > 0
   AND sum(date = '2016-07-06') = 0
```

Comment: I have never seen this syntax, not even after googling for it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customer FROM table t
  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table t1
                 WHERE date = '2016-07-07' AND t.customer = t1.customer)
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table t2 
                   WHERE date = '2016-07-06' AND t.customer = t2.customer)
  GROUP BY customer
```